# Entity Framework Tools uses Production as the default environment value

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

On an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application I am running the command:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

To create the database from migrations ...

However the command picks the connection string from **Production** settings and not from **Development** settings.

The Program.cs of the application is the following:

```
  public class Program {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {    
      BuildWebHost(args).Run();       
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(String[] args) {

      IWebHostBuilder builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

      IWebHost host = builder
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configuration) => {

          IHostingEnvironment environment = context.HostingEnvironment;

          configuration
            .AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"settings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", false, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

          if (environment.IsDevelopment()) {     
            configuration.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();            
          }          

        })
        .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) => { })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

      return host;

    }

  }
```

How to make the Entity Framework tools to use Development environment?

Comment: can you also provide settings.{EnvironmentName}.json for both production and development and settings.json, atleast connection strings part. However issue may rise because of setting connection string in settings.json

Comment: Is the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable set? The tools should default to *Development* if not.

Comment: Somehow when I restarted Visual Studio it started to work ... Have no idea why but it works.